# Outlook contact folders (Categories) subscription API issue

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-api

API Availability? - Is there any APIs to subscribe   **create contact category resource**?
We are currently using the [contact folder subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for that we are facing the below issue.

Issue description - For the create/update contact, we do not receive any notification from Microsoft for graph and graph beta API.

Details used:

Request body: {"notificationUrl":"","expirationDateTime":"2023-27-06T04:15:43Z","resource":"/me/contactFolders/<%contactFolderid%>/contacts","changeType":"created,updated,deleted","clientState":""}

API used - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions (Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http))

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0#maximum-length-of-subscription-per-resource-type) maximum length of subscription for `contacts` resource is 4230 minutes (under 3 days).

Your `expirationDateTime=2023-27-06T04:15:43Z` is strange. Based on expected format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ` you set the month to 27.

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#resources-examples) probably only resources `/me/contacts` or `/users/{user_id}/contacts` are supported, not `/me/contactFolders/<%contactFolderid%>/contacts`.

Try to create a subscription with `expirationDateTime` that doesn't exceed 3 days

```
{
    "notificationUrl":"<your_notification_url>",
    "expirationDateTime":"2023-01-28T04:15:43Z",
    "resource":"/me/contactFolders/<%contactFolderid%>/contacts",
    "changeType":"created,updated,deleted",
    "clientState":""
}
```

If possible in your case you can use [delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/contact-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to periodically get a set of contacts that have been added, deleted, or updated in a specified folder.

```
GET /me/contactFolders/{id}/contacts/delta
GET /users/{id}/contactFolders/{id}/contacts/delta
```